# Regex in match \ and :

Tags: regex

Capture first part of string with trailing delimiter ':' or '\'

**REGEX**

```
^([^:\]+)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PATTERN ERROR
```

**DATA**

```
TEST:TEST
TEST\TEST
```

**GOAL**

```
TEST
TEST
```

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/0NkHIJ/1)

Comment: ```\``` is used to escape, try escaping your ```\```: `^([^:\\]+)`

Comment: very good, thanks brother!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^([^:\\]+[:\\])

TEST:TEST # Matches TEST
TEST\TEST # Matches TEST
TESTisgood # No match
```